# Catkin doesn't works with Bison

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm having issues trying to compile a little program with a CMakeList that uses a Bison/Flex parser.

When I use catkin the system gives me the following error:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/leontes/Dropbox/ros_ws/build"
####
[  1%] [BISON][parser] Building parser with bison 3.0.2
Scanning dependencies of target task_executor
make[2]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo «../htn_planner/src/parser.hpp», necesario para «ROSbtp/task_executor/CMakeFiles/task_executor.dir/__/htn_planner/src/lexer.cpp.o».  Alto.
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
[  2%] Building CXX object ROSbtp/task_executor/CMakeFiles/task_executor.dir/__/htn_planner/src/parser.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from ../htn_planner/yacc/parser.yy:35:0:
/home/leontes/Dropbox/ros_ws/src/ROSbtp/task_executor/../htn_planner/include/sortgoal.hh: In member function ‘bool CriteriaF::operator()(Unifier*, Unifier*) const’:
/home/leontes/Dropbox/ros_ws/src/ROSbtp/task_executor/../htn_planner/include/sortgoal.hh:68:30: warning: variable ‘e’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  criteriacit i = f->begin(), e = f->end();
                              ^
make[1]: *** [ROSbtp/task_executor/CMakeFiles/task_executor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Catkin launchs Bison, Bison generates parser.cpp and parser.hpp but catkin insists that theres no rule to build that parser.hpp file. And of course I delete this files catkin not even launchs the compilation.

The CMakeLists that I've writed is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(task_executor)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED cmake_modules)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME})

#Set headers directory
include_directories("include" "../htn_planner/include")

#Set source files
file(GLOB SOURCES "../htn_planner/src/*.cpp")
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../htn_planner/src/parser.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../htn_planner/src/parser.hpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../htn_planner/src/lexer.cpp")

#Build commands for Flex and Bison
find_package(FLEX)
find_package(BISON)

FLEX_TARGET(lexer  ../htn_planner/yacc/lexer.ll ../htn_planner/src/lexer.cpp)
BISON_TARGET(parser ../htn_planner/yacc/parser.yy ../htn_planner/src/parser.cpp)


ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(lexer parser)

#Add a binary executable
add_executable(task_executor nodes/task_executor.cpp ../htn_planner/planner_api/planner_api.cpp ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS} ${FLEX_lexer_OUTPUTS} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(task_executor readline ${EXTRALIBS} ${PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't know what to do, I'm run out of ideas...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223002/catkin-doesn%27t-works-with-bison/) by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
Just a note: catkin is essentially CMake. When you write "Catkin launchs Bison [..]", it should really be "CMake launches Bison". This may seem pedantic, but it will make searching for potential solutions much easier, as the CMake community is much larger than that of catkin.

**Comment by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on 2015-12-23**:
Nope, the problem is with Catkin and how it resolves dependencies and execute the packages. The same Cmakelist (without the catkin directives) works fine when run as a standalone proyect.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
Can you try and see whether using absolute paths works? You can prefix the paths to `../htn_planner` with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-23**:
@Leontes can you expand on why you think it is related to how catkin handles resolving dependencies or "execute the packages"? Based on that I have no idea what may be the source of the issue. I don't see anything in the above CMakeLists.txt which would lead me to believe it is a catkin problem.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-23**:
On further inspection I think I noticed an issue, and I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't seem to have a declared dependency between the `task_executor` target (created with `add_executable`) and the targets for generating the files with flex and bison. My guess is that running `catkin_make -j1 ...` would possibly work around the issue, and that adding a line like `add_dependencies(task_executor lexer parser)` would fix the problem for multi-threaded builds.

If that doesn't work, you mentioned that as a normal CMake package it worked. Could you post that CMake project? Can you try building that CMake project with `make -j2` to see if you can reproduce the issue with the plain CMake project?

It seems to me that the most likely cause is that `catkin_make` defaults `-jN` where `N` is the number of cores on your computer, but you didn't do that when running `cmake`/`make` manually.

Hopefully that helps,

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
That was my first thought as well, but the *"No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo [..] parser.hpp [..] necesario para [..] parser.cpp.o"* seems to suggest that `make` can't figure out where to find `parser.hpp` (*"no rule to make target .."*). That would suggest something else.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-23**:
"No rule to make target..." implies two things: the file doesn't exist, and make doesn't have a rule to create it. (if the file already existed, make wouldn't need a rule). I would think that the bison command would declare two output files, but it appears to only declare that it creates the .cpp.

**Comment by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on 2015-12-23**:
When I compile the program with the original CMake I usually use `make -j8` and it works fine. I fix the problem setting manually `parser.cpp parser.h and lexer.cpp` in the src or include directories, deleting the Bison/Flex directives and compiling as usual.

**Comment by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on 2015-12-23**:
The `add_dependencies(task_executor lexer parser)` fix doesn't works. Same error with parser.hpp.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-24**:
@Leontes: I wouldn't call that a 'fix', more a workaround.

**Comment by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on 2015-12-24**:
@gvdhoorn You are right, but I can't lose so much time trying to figure why the dependencies aren't resolved before catkin builds `task_executor` and the generation of these files It's a minor feature that a want to add to the CmakeList. There's no problem if can't include the Bison/Flex directives.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-24**:
Another workaround to try might be to move the FLEX_TARGET and BISON_TARGET above the catkin_package call. The theory being that catkin_package changes the `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` which might be affecting flex/bison's generation.